# Does a programming language with the following features exist?

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, language-design

Is there a language which will support the following concept or is there a pattern to achieve something similar with existing one?

**Concept**

I want to define a `Rectangle` with the following properties: `Length`, `Height`, `Area`, `Perimeter`; where `Area = Length * Height` and `Perimeter = (2 * Length) + (2 * Height)`.

Given the statement above, if I want to create a `Rectangle` by giving it a `Length` and a `Height`, it should of course automatically fill out the rest of the properties.

However, it should go further and automatically allow you to create a `Rectangle` with any two properties (say `Height` and `Perimeter`) because that is also mathematically enough to create the same `Rectangle`.

**Example**

To help explain the idea, take this example:

```
//Declaration
Rectangle
{
    Height, Length, Area, Perimeter;

    Area = Height * Length;
    Perimeter = (2 * Length) + (2 * Height);
}

//Usage
main()
{
    var rectangleA = new Rectangle(Height, Length);
    var rectangleB = new Rectangle(Height, Area);

    Assert(rectangleA == rectangleB);
}
```

> Notice how I didn't need to define constructors for `Rectangle`. Notice I did not need specify the specific logic needed if a `Rectangle` was created using `Height` and `Area`.

Edit: Should be rectangle and not a square for a proper example.

Comment: Sounds a little like Haskell's typeclasses, but I don't know them well enough to add that as an answer.

Comment: This sounds a lot more like a library and not a programming language

Comment: Yes. Javascript. Check out getters and setters (no, not the design pattern, the language feature)

Comment: There was an OOPSLA paper about this in the 1980s, where you could define e.g. Area as the product of Length and Breadth, and the type system understood that, so wouldn't let you use units with not only the wrong types but the wrong dimensions.

Comment: @slebetman If you can show me an example in Javascript that would be awesome. Write an answer!

Comment: Plenty of languages can have code written in them that will allow this, but very few will do it *for* you. You may need to look at something at the level of MATLAB or Maple.

Comment: I misunderstood your initial description. What I thought was: `a = new Square(); a.width = 100;a.height = 50;console.log(a.area)`. That is, properties that alter other properties without directly calling functions/methods.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yup, that is exactly the point. It is trivial to write a computed property, what I am looking for is a smart language that can infer more rules from the initial ones.

Comment: @GordonGustafson Yeah, something tells me that Haskell is the magic unicorn I've been looking for ... I'm definitely gong to look into it.

Comment: NB No [tag:design-patterns] here. This is about [tag:programming-languages] and [tag:language-design].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course such a language exists. Many do, as you've now pointed out in your own comment to this answer.

In the example below I'll be using the [Powerloom](http://www.isi.edu/isd/LOOM/PowerLoom/) representation system, implemented in a language called [STELLA](http://www.isi.edu/isd/LOOM/Stella/). 
You can play with it from within a [Common Lisp](https://common-lisp.net/) environment.
Once you have everything installed you can load the language by running:

```
(cl:load "load-powerloom.lisp")
(in-package "STELLA")
(in-dialect "KIF")
```

That's about all you need to start building awesome geometrical objects.
Within STELLA you may define a concept with the primitive `defconcept`:

```
(defconcept Rectangle (?r)
  :documentation "Curious geometrical objects that live on a plane.")
```

And define its properties with `deffunction`:

```
(deffunction rect-height ((?t Rectangle)) :-> (?n INTEGER))
(deffunction rect-length ((?t Rectangle)) :-> (?n INTEGER))
(deffunction area ((?t Rectangle)) :-> (?n INTEGER))
(deffunction perimeter ((?t Rectangle)) :-> (?n INTEGER))
```

To make the relations between area, perimeter and the sides of your rectangle, you'll have to make some assertions. That's what you'll have `assert` for.

```
(assert (forall (?t Rectangle)
                (= (area ?t) (* (rect-height ?t) (rect-length ?t)))))
(assert (forall (?t Rectangle)
                (= (perimeter ?t) (+ (* 2 (rect-height ?t))
                                     (* 2 (rect-length ?t))))))
```

You are telling STELLA that for all rectangles, the area is the product of height and length, and that for all rectangles, the perimeter is twice the height plus twice the length.

Now you can instantiate your objects, and it doesn't matter what properties you give it, as long as they make sense.

```
(definstance rect1 :Rectangle true :rect-height 10 :rect-length 10)
(definstance rect2 :Rectangle true :area 40 :rect-height 20)
```

Here  you instantiate `rect1` with height and length as parameters, and `rect2` with area and height.

But its always good to check that the language is doing what you expect:

```
STELLA> (retrieve all ?x (= (area rect1) ?x))
There is 1 solution:
  #1: ?X=100

STELLA> (retrieve all ?x (= (rect-length rect2) ?x))
There is 1 solution:
  #1: ?X=2
```

If you ever get tired of rectangles and decide to build a beautiful square, why not derive a concept?

```
(defconcept Square ((?r Rectangle))
  :documentation "Weird rectangles that fascinated the Greeks"
  :<=> (= (rect-height ?r) (rect-length ?r)))
```

Simply tell STELLA that squares are rectangles where height and length are equal.

Now try it out:

```
STELLA> (definstance nice-rectangle :Rectangle true :rect-length 10 :area 100)
|i|NICE-RECTANGLE
STELLA> (ask (Square nice-rectangle))
TRUE
```

I'm not an expert at all, but I find the language fascinating. It's sad that there is so little information about it on the internet. Even the manual is incomplete.
For more information I'd suggest starting with [these slides](http://www.isi.edu/isd/LOOM/PowerLoom/documentation/PowerLoom-Overview-Slides.pdf).

The famous book SICP teaches how to build a nondeterministic evaluator for such a language [here.](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-29.html#%25_sec_4.4)
And finally, a wonderful write up describing motivations and applications behind these ideas can be seen [here](https://chriskohlhepp.wordpress.com/reasoning-systems/the-reasoned-lisper/).

Comment: I respect this answer

Comment: Wow, this sounds extremely promising!!

Comment: So, it looks like I was looking for Logic Based Languages - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages_by_type#Logic-based_languages - I think the essence of what I was looking for was "Logic-based languages specify a set of attributes that a solution must have, rather than a set of steps to obtain a solution."

Comment: Congratulations - +1 because you well understood the question.

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is a language with an integrated computer algebra system. It has to be able to resolve equations with respect to different variables.

While it would be possible to implement something like this, I doubt that it would make sense because in many cases there will be either no solution or multiple solutions.

Even your simple example will not work if only area and perimeter are given because there will usually be two solutions. (I assume that your class actually represents a rectangle and not a square, otherwise you should not have separate variables for length and height.)

Example:

```
Input: area = 2, perimeter = 6
Solution 1: length = 2, height = 1
Solution 2: length = 1, height = 2
```

Another remark not really related to your question: Your class obviously contains redundant member variables. This is a bad thing for various reasons, the most important being the possibility of inconsistencies. Unless you have ***very*** strict performance constraints, you should store only two of them, say length and width, and provide methods to calculate the others when needed.

Comment: You are right, given an `Area` and a `Perimeter` there may be more than one solution. In that case, there would never be a constructor for that. Or better yet, that constructor would return a list of possible `Rectangles`.

Comment: Yes, I do have redundant variables. Which is actually what motivates the question. How do you know which ones are the real ones and which ones are derived?

Comment: @hatcyl: To decide which variables to use, two criteria come to my mind: (1) The ones that need to be accessed more often. (2) The ones from which the others can more easily be calculated. In your example I would avoid storing area and perimeter because calculating the other values would involve a square root.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, you can use properties, which have implicit getters and setters. That way you can write something like:

```
public class Square {
    public int Length {
        get { return length; }
        set { length = value; }
    }
    public int Area {
        get { return length * length; }
        set { length = Math.Sqrt(value); }
    }
    public int Perimeter {
        get { return length * 4; }
        set { length = value / 4; }
    }
    private int length;
}
```

Now you can write:

```
Square square = new Square();
square.Length = 2;
Console.WriteLine(square.Length);    // "2"
Console.WriteLine(square.Area);      // "4"
Console.WriteLine(square.Perimeter); // "8"
square.Area = 9;
Console.WriteLine(square.Length);    // "3"
Console.WriteLine(square.Area);      // "9"
Console.WriteLine(square.Perimeter); // "12"
```

**Edit:**

C# also allows you name properties at your choosing when instantiating an object:

```
Square square1 = new Square { Perimeter = 12 };
Square square2 = new Square { Length = 4 };
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question because you have to explicitly define how each property is calculated.

Comment: Yes, this is practically my go to method right now. I am essentially trying to find a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Computers don't know anything about things we call "rectangles", they need us to set these rules one way or another ;-)

Comment: Yes, but a computer should know that if `Area = Length * Width` then `Length = Area / Width`.

Comment: @Tim Straubinger Now you have me wondering, how would your above example look with both a `Length` and a `Width`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think something like this does exist in the form of a programming language.

### Ontology

However the first approach I can think about is defining an Ontology, I mean a set of rules about

1. Entities: Rectangle, Square, Dog, Car, etc...
2. Attributes: Area, Height, Number of Wheels, etc...
3. Relations between (1) and (2): Rectangle's Area is Height * Width, ...

Now given a list of attributes and the required output Entity

> I have `height` and `width` and I need a `Rectangle`

the system could search for a path through the rules graph to produce the required outcome based on the provided inputs.

### Real world example

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com) probably follows the technique described above

[image]

[image]